# How to resolve error when initializing MobileServiceClient Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

This is my code:

```
MobileServiceClient a = new MobileServiceClient("http://appitalo.azurewebsites.net/");
```

When I try to execute this code in my Xamarin.Forms android app, I get the following message[image]

Does somebody have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> platform specific assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext

(Assuming you are talking at the deprecated `Mobile Services` vs. `App Services`)

Make sure that you have added the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` Nuget package to each of your projects, *including* the application projects as there are platform-specific libraries that need to be included.

```
├── Xamarin.iOS10
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── monoandroid
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── monotouch
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── net45
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── netcore45
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.pri
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch+monoandroid
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
├── wp8
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.UI.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.UI.xml
│   ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
│   └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
└── wpa81
    ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
    ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.xml
    ├── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
    └── Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that the problem is the fact that I created a PCL project, now I created a Shared Project and the dependency show up

Comment: @ItaloPessoa You can use a PCL project, you need to add the package to all of your projects.

Comment: The package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext doesn't exist in Nugget, and I couldn't found on the internet

Comment: @ItaloPessoa `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext` is platform specific `.dll` within the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` nuget. In it is in the tree of files in my answer. Install that nuget in your "native" application projects AND your PCL library

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover